# Why does Jensen's imply this?

Tags: convex, inequality

Let $F$ be a convex function. If $Y$ and $Z$ are independent random variables and $EZ=0$, then $$EF(Y) = EF(Y+EZ)\leq E(Y+Z).$$

I fail to understand why the last inequality is true. Can someone explain how this comes from Jensen's?

Taken from page 2 in [this paper](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~romanv/papers/decoupling-simple.pdf).

Comment: Once you account for $E(Z)=0$, the last inequality *is* Jensen's Inequality.

Comment: Is there a typo here? Otherwise set $F(x)=cx$, where $c$ is large enough so that $EF(Y+EZ)>E(Y+Z)$.

Comment: How is $E[F(Y)] \leq E(Y+Z)$ Jensen's? How do I get rid of the $F$ on the RHS?

Comment: $E[F(Y)] \le E[Y] = E[Y]+0 = E[Y+Z].$

Comment: Hmmm, didn't know $E[F(Y)]\leq E[Y]$

Comment: @whuber: I'm really confused. What if $E[Y]=1$ and $F(Y)=2Y$?

Comment: $E[Y^2]\not\leq E[Y]$ on [1,2] for example.

Comment: @Alex I apologize for creating confusion here: of course the "$F$" has to appear on both sides.  It's late in the week and time to quit... .

Comment: Interesting, so this paper has a typo then. Obnoxious.

Answer (score 3):

Okay so thanks to my friend pointing it out, it turns out there WAS a typo in the paper.

It should have said $EF(Y) = EF(Y+EZ)\leq EF(Y+Z)$. So the RHS follows from applying conditional Jensen's (conditioning on Y).

$E[F(Y+EZ)] = E[F(E[(Y+Z)|Y])] \leq E(E(F(Y+Z)|Y)) = E[F(Y+Z)].$